# Android, How to remove a view from UI?

Tags: android, dynamic, view, addition

In my main page of my application, server sends me some flags. One of then is advertise flag. if it is set to true i need to show advertise and if it is set to false i shouldn't show it.

now, the problem. I need to put the space of advertise in XML file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<RileativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip">

</RileativeLayout>

.
.
.
</LinearLayout >
```

according to above code if the flag is set to false, i don't show advertise but the gap is still remain in my screen. How to remove it from my code dynamically and shift other views (which are blow of it) up?

Comment: view.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: This will do the job `findViewById(R.id.adv).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned above in the comments for your question: a view has a few different View options.

- **View.VISIBLE:** this means that it's visible and can be seen by the user.
- **View.INVISIBLE:** this means the view is still in the layout but cannot be seen by the user (the user can't interact with it either).
- **View.GONE:** this means the view is destroyed and is no longer part of it.

to remove a View completely from the layout you should use `View.GONE`, if you're going to make it visible you should use `View,INVISIBLE`.

Answer (score 1):

try this when your flag is false

```
add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "remove" the View by changing the visibility of it. Use

```
View ad = findViewById(R.id.adv);
ad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```